# Slow meta query in WordPress checking for empty value

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I've inherited a WordPress website from a previous developer and a particular webpage has started loading slowly (due to an increase in the number of records being retrieved).

The records are retrieved by a meta query...

```
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key' => 'inspectioncomments',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '!='
        ),
    );
```

"InspectionComments" is a custom field on a custom type. For this page, any post that has an "InspectionComments" value is to be displayed (i.e not null). It works a expected but is slow.

I'm an intermediate WordPress developer and from my reading many have had the issue with this being slow, but I was wondering is there are definitive way to fix this? Would adding in a common bit of text to every post and doing something like below work or is there an alternative way?

There are a lot of posts already there so I'm looking to see what is the best way to remediate this without editing the current data too much (if at all!)

```
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'inspectioncomments',
                'value'   => 'Common Text',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, comparing in the query with `like` is more slow than `=`, so i think you should stick with it (`=`). But i think you can introduce date criteria in your query wich narrow down the fetched data interval and make things going much faster.
***But it realy depends on your use case***.
If you can fetch only records from a certain period, this should help you.
this article illustrate my point of vue : https://docs.wpvip.com/how-tos/optimize-core-queries-at-scale/